# Which teams have won the most championships in the four major American sports leagues?

Tags: trivia, history, major-leagues

Which teams have won the most championships in the four major American sports leagues (NFL, MLB, NBA, NHL)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**NFL: Green Bay Packers**

- *9 NFL titles* [before the Super Bowl Era]: 1929, 1930, 1931, 1936, 1939,
  1944, 1961, 1962, 1965
- *4 Super Bowl titles*: 1966, 1967, 1996, 2010

**NBA: Boston Celtics**

- *17 NBA titles*: 1957, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966,
  1968, 1969, 1974, 1976, 1981, 1984, 1986, 2008

**NHL: Montreal Canadiens**

- *3 NHL titles*: 1919, 1924, 1925
- *24 Stanley Cup titles*: 1916<sub>†</sub>, 1924<sub>†</sub>, 1930, 1931, 1944, 1946, 1953,
  1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1965, 1966, 1968, 1969, 1971, 1973,
  1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1986, 1993

**MLB: New York Yankees**

- *27 World Series titles*: 1923, 1927, 1928, 1932, 1936, 1937, 1938,
  1939, 1941, 1943, 1947, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1956, 1958,
  1961, 1962, 1977, 1978, 1996, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2009

***As of 2016**

<sub>† - These Stanley Cup titles were won during an interleague tournament including league champions from the [National Hockey Association (NHA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Hockey_Association) (dissolved in 1917 and replaced by the NHL), the [Pacific Coast Hockey Association (PCHA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Coast_Hockey_Association), and the [Western Canada Hockey League (WCHL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Canada_Hockey_League). The PCHA and WCHL merged to form the Western Hockey League (WHL) in 1925 only to dissolve a season later. Thus, the NHL became the only league to compete for the Stanley Cup in 1926 and has been the championship trophy for the NHL since.</sub>

Comment: Should it be pointed out that the first 2 Stanley Cup championships for the Canadiens were *not* as NHL champions (indeed, the NHL didn't even exist when they won the first...)? This is sort of the opposite of the Packers :)  The Canadiens were also the NHL champions in 1919, 1924 (won the Cup separately) and 1925.