# NHL Playoff Clean Sweep

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, stanley-cup

After reading [How many times has a 4 game sweep occurred during the Stanley Cup finals?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4919/how-many-times-has-a-sweep-occurred-during-the-stanley-cup-finals), I was curious if there has ever been a team who has not lost a game during the NHL playoff to win the cup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Has there] ever been a team who has not lost a game during the NHL playoffs to win the [Stanley] cup?

Since 1939 (the first [best-of-seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1939_Stanley_Cup_Finals) Stanley Cup finals), this has taken place only twice, albeit during the era in which there were only six teams in the league (and two playoff rounds).

- [1960](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1960.html) - Montreal Canadiens
- [1952](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1952.html) - Detroit Red Wings

Between [1926](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/1984)-1938, this took place five times:

- [1930](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1930.html) - Montreal Canadiens
- [1929](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1929.html) - Boston Bruins
- [1927](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1927.html) - Ottawa Senators
- [1926](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1926.html), [1935](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1935.html) - Montreal Maroons

---

Since 1939 (the first [best-of-seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1939_Stanley_Cup_Finals) Stanley Cup finals), the following teams lost only once on their way to the Stanley Cup:

- [1948](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1948.html), [1949](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1949.html) - Toronto Maple Leafs
- [1944](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1944.html), [1946](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1946.html), [1968](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1968.html) <sub>†</sub>, [1976](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1976.html) <sub>‡</sub> - Montreal Canadiens

<sub>† - 12 teams in the league (three playoff rounds) 
 ‡ - 18 teams in the league (three playoff rounds, division winners earned a bye to the quarterfinals)</sub>

Between [1926](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/1984)-1938, the following teams lost only once on their way to the Stanley Cup:

- [1936](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1936.html) - Detroit Red Wings
- [1934](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1934.html) - Chicago Black Hawks
- [1933](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1933.html) - New York Rangers
- [1932](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1932.html) - Toronto Maple Leafs

Comment: Damn, so Canadiens are the only ones with more than 2 rounds to ever come close? Makes me feel good as a fan (granted I did expect them to be part of this stat if they were) 2 rounds is less impressive, thanks for including only 1 loss with 3 rounds.

Comment: @akadian There are the [Edmonton Oilers of 1988](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1988.html), who lost twice over four rounds. In general, however, nobody has come closer than that in four playoff rounds.